# In python, why can't I terminate each of processes in a for loop, then block until if all of them are terminated in another for loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing

In python, why can't I terminate each of processes in a for loop, then block until if all of them are terminated in another for loop.

For example:

```
for i in range(len(processes)):
    processes[i].terminate()
    time.sleep(a year)
    processes[i].join()
```

is ok, but

```
for i in range(len(processes)):
    processes[i].terminate()
for i in range(len(processes)):
    processes[i].join()
```

returns that I can only join on process that started.

Comment: Show an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including creation and start of the processes.

Comment: Please show a working example demonstrating the problem. The stuff you've shown can't happen. In that second case, if the process wasn't started, the terminate call would fail. You can do the joins in a separate loop. The error says you didn't actually start the processes and you aren't showing that code. You'd only need a dozen more lines of code - at most - to properly demonstrate.

Comment: tdelaney's point helped me to find the probelm, it is somewhere else.